Why do we pray to Kartaviryarjuna when something is lost?
Why do we pray to Kartaviryarjuna when something is lost? I do not know whether it happens in other parts of India. I'm unsure whether this practice is prevalent throughout Bengal. However, in our place, if we have lost some things (say jewellery or anything) people pray to Kartaviryarjuna.
Who is Kartaviryarjuna? I guess, he is not the famous Arjuna from Mahabharata. Why is he called when someone has lost something?

He is also prayed in south when something is lost. There is a Shloka/mantram on him. He is the incarnation of Sudharshana Chakram. And killed by Parashurama and was a devotee of Dhattatreya.

कार्तवीर्यार्जुनो नाम राजा बाहु सहस्रवान्
तस्य संस्मरणादेव हृतं नष्टं च लभ्यते
maybe this is the Shloka. it was in telugu script but I typed in devanagari so I don't know transliteration is correct or not

The worship of Kartaviryarjuna dates back to the medieval era. His worship is prescribed for recovering lost/kidnapped goods & people alongside subduing influence of thieves. This might come from the fact that Ravana, the kidnapper of Sita, had been mightily harassed & captured by Kartavirya. The worship of Kartavirya was quite popular in North India During the Muslim rule (for obvious reasons), but died out during the British rule. Today it is stil seen among some Rajput communities, who venerate him as their ancestor.

I) Your first question Who is Kartaviryarjuna?
Srimad Bhagavatam [Book-9, chapter 23, verses: 23-27] says a few lines about Arjuna (he was the son of Kritavirya and hence called Kartaviryarjuna), in the verses as given here.

दुर्मदो भद्रसेनस्य धनकः कृतवीर्यसूः ।
कृताग्निः कृतवर्मा च कृतौजा धनकात्मजाः ॥ २३ ॥
Durmada and Dhanaka were the sons begotten by Bhadrasena, and Dhanaka
gave life to the sons Kritavîrya, Kritâgni, Kritavarmâ and Kritaujâ. ॥
23 ॥
अर्जुनः कृतवीर्यस्य सप्तद्वीपेश्वरोऽभवत् ।
दत्तात्रेयात् हरेरंशात् प्राप्तयोगमहागुणः ॥ २४ ॥
From Kritavîrya there was Arjuna [Kârtavîryârjuna] who became emperor
over the seven continents. From Lord Dattâtreya, an [amsa] incarnation
of the Supreme Personality, he obtained all the great qualities [the
eight siddhis] of yoga.  ॥ 24 ॥
न नूनं कार्तवीर्यस्य गतिं यास्यन्ति पार्तिवाः ।
यज्ञदानतपोयोगश्रुतवीर्यजयादिभिः ॥ २५ ॥
No one on earth could equal Kârtavîrya's qualities of sacrifice,
charity, austerity, mystic potency, education, strength and mercy.॥ 25
॥
पञ्चाशीतिसहस्राणि ह्यव्याहतबलःसमाः ।
अनष्टवित्तस्मरणो बुभुजेऽक्षय्यषड्वसु ॥ २६ ॥
[Under his rule] for eighty-five thousand years the six forms of
pleasure [as derived from the senses and  the mind] were enjoyed with
an undiminished strength, continuous opulence and unfailing memory. ॥
26 ॥
तस्य पुत्रसहस्रेषु पञ्चैवोर्वरिता मृधे ।
जयध्वजः शूरशेनो वॄषभो मधुरूर्जितः ॥ २७ ॥
In the fight [against Parasurâma] only five of his thousands of sons
remained alive: Jayadhvaja, S'ûrasena, Vrishabha, Madhu and Ûrjita. ॥
27 ॥

II) Your second question I guess, he is not the famous Arjuna from Mahabharata.
Yes, Arjuna, belonged to Dvapara yuga, son of Pandu and Kunti, amsa of Indra  whereas Kartaviryarjuna, an avatara of Bhagavan Vishnu's Sudarsana Cakra, lived in Treta yoga, who was son of Kritavirya, and was contemporary to Yogi Dattatreya and Bhagavan Parasurama.
In Narada Purana [Chapater-76], Rishi Sanathkumara told Devarishi Narada about Kartaviryarjuna in the following four slokas [3-6]:

Listen O Narada, to what I shall say for dispelling your doubts and as
to how Kartavirya has attained the status of one worthy of being
served.॥ 3 ॥
He was the incarnation of Sudaréana Cakra on the earth. After
propitiating Dattatreya he attained excellent brilliance. ॥ 4 ॥
O Narada, by the mere remembrance of that leading king one is able to
conquer enemies in the battle and immediately get back what is lost. ॥
5 ॥
Hence his mantra,! worship etc. are kept secret in all the Tantras. I
shall reveal it to you. It bestows the highest attainments [siddhis] ॥
6 ॥

III) Your third and final question Why is he called when someone has lost something?
From Narada Purana [Chapater-76], as given in (II), let us cull out verse-5:

O Narada, by the mere remembrance of that leading king one is able to
conquer enemies in the battle and immediately get back what is lost. ॥
5 ॥

This verse mentions that just by remembering this great king, one will get back what is lost! Thus, by reciting Kartaviryarjuna Stotram, on can get back what is lost. This stotram is given below:
कार्तवीर्यार्जुनो नाम राजा बाहुसहस्रवान् । 
तस्य स्मरणमात्रेण गतं नष्टं च लभ्यते ॥ १॥  
Om Salutations to Karthaveeryarjuna, The king who has several hands,
Just my remembering him, The loss which occurred would be got.॥ 1 ॥

कार्तवीर्यः खलद्वेषी कृतवीर्यसुतो बली ।  
सहस्रबाहुः शत्रुघ्नो रक्तवासा धनुर्धरः ॥ २॥ 
Kartha veerya, hater of wicked, son of krutha veerya, strong one,
Thousand handed one, killer of enemies, One who lives in bloody
battles, One who holds a bow. ॥ 2 ॥

रक्तगन्धो रक्तमाल्यो राजा स्मर्तुरभीष्टदः ।
द्वादशैतानि नामानि कार्तवीर्यस्य यः पठेत् ॥ ३॥  
सम्पदस्तत्र जायन्ते जनस्तत्र वशं गतः ।
आनयत्याशु दूरस्थं क्षेमलाभयुतं प्रियम् ॥ ४॥ 
One with smell of blood, One who wears a garland of blood , King ,
One who is to be remembered, one who is desirable, If these twelve
names of Karthaveerya are read, Wealth will accumulate there, people
will be under their control, Undesirable things will go far and safety
and profit will come near.॥ 3-4 ॥

सहस्रबाहुसशरं महितं सचापं रक्ताम्बरं रक्तकिरीटकुण्डलम् ।
चोरादि-दुष्टभय-नाशं इष्टदं तं ध्यायेत् महाबल-विजृम्भित-कार्तवीर्यम् ॥ ५॥ 
I meditate on the very strong and blossoming Kartha Veerya, Who has
thousand hands, who is honoured, holds bow and arrows, Who wears
bloddy cloths, who decorated with crowns soaked in different bloods,
Who destroya the fear to thieves and bad people and fulfills desires. ॥ 5 ॥

यस्य स्मरणमात्रेण सर्वदुःखक्षयो भवेत् । 
यन्नामानि महावीर्यश्चार्जुनः कृतवीर्यवान्᳚ ॥ ६॥ 
As soon as one rememvbers this all sorrow would be destroyed, And
these names of the great hero, would make, Valorous people as great
as Karthaveeryarjuna. ॥ 6 ॥

हैहयाधिपतेः स्तोत्रं सहस्रावृत्तिकारितम् । 
वाञ्चितार्थप्रदं नृणां स्वराज्यं सुकृतं यदि ॥ ७॥ 
This prayer of the Lord of the Hehaya clan, if read thousand times,
Would definitely fulfill all that is desired and also, Get him his
own country if he has good luck.॥ 7 ॥

  ॥  इति कार्तवीर्य द्वादशनाम स्तोत्रम् ॥    
॥  Thus ends the prayer of twelve names of Kartha veeryarjuna  ॥

Good Luck!
